# exctract url from vimeo feed channel and regex

Tags: regex, url, feed, vimeo, channel

i need exctract from feed of vimeo channel the url of video without
the word /channel/name

example feed: vimeo.com/channels/nudiecutie/videos/rss

example video url : http://vimeo.com/channels/nudiecutie/57383513

I need function for change link to http://vimeo.com/57383513 from the result of rss

Comment: what language u use? and did the video id consist only digit?

Comment: i use php and you can see how i receive data from feed in my precedent question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467015/get-all-data-from-vimeo-feed-and-store-in-database

Answer (score 1):

```
if(  preg_match( '#.+?(\d+)$#', ' http://vimeo.com/channels/nudiecutie/57383513', $matches ))
{
    $url = 'http://vimeo.com/' . $matches[1]; //$url contain your desired pattern
}
```

Is this what you want? It grab the video id and concatenate to `http:vimeo.com/`

Comment: you can explane me more. Sorry but i don't understand in so cryptical mode

Comment: Thanks slier !! you can explane me how i can filter all url i retrieve from array of multiple feed in my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14467015/get-all-data-from-vimeo-feed-and-store-in-database